# Read a file and create an array every time a string appears

Tags: python

I want to read a file which have strings, like headers, and then an array. I wanna generate a python array for each block and save them in a different file, like LI 1 below would be an array 4 x 4.

```
LI 1
10. 20. 30. 40.
10. 21. 30. 40.
10. 22. 31. 43.
10. 23. 35. 45.

LI 2
11. 20. 40. 50.
11.2 22. 42. 52.

LI 3
15. 23. 40. 50.
15. 24. 41. 51.
15.2 25. 42. 52.

LI 10
10.3 26. 30. 40.
10.2 27. 30. 40.
10.3 28. 31. 43.

LI 3
15. 23. 40. 50.
15. 24. 41. 51.
15.2 25. 42. 52.
```

I know how to do it typing the string "LI 1", "LI 2".... but also there is an issue when LI (number) repeats, like 'LI 3' in the example below, because I wanna them to be in different files. For the file below I would like to have 5 different outputs. What should be the correct approach? At the moment I did, for 'LI 2' for example:

```
with open(file) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if 'LI 2' in line:
            found_type = True
            continue
        if found_type:
            if 'LI' in line: 
                found_type = False #stops when reach the next LI
            else:
                x.append(line[2:15])
                y.append(line[16:29])
                d1.append(line[31:43])
                d2.append(line[45:57])

xf=filter(None,x)
yf=filter(None,y)           
d1f=filter(None,d1)
d2f=filter(None,d2)

out=np.array([xf,yf,d1f,d2f])        
out=out.T.astype(np.float)

np.savetxt('LI_2.dat',out,delimiter=' ',fmt='%1.8f')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, may work. Read the lines then do number transform. From your code, I'm not sure if you want to do separate filtering and file for each block or all blocks combined. So I assumed the former. Hope this helps!

```
import string
import random

lines = ''
output_folder ='folder/'
with open(file) as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()

for line in lines:
    if 'LI' in line:
        x=[]
        y=[]
        d1=[]
        d2=[]
        output = output_folder + line.strip()+ random.choice(string.letters) + '.dat'
    elif line =='\n':
        pass
    else:
        numbers = line.split()
        x.append(float(numbers[0]))
        y.append(float(numbers[1]))
        d1.append(float(numbers[2]))
        d2.append(float(numbers[3]))
        xf=filter(None,x)
        yf=filter(None,y)           
        d1f=filter(None,d1)
        d2f=filter(None,d2)
        out=np.array([xf,yf,d1f,d2f])        
        out=out.T.astype(np.float)
        np.savetxt(output,out,delimiter=' ',fmt='%1.8f')
```

Comment: Really thanks Emmanuel, this was amazing! I just needed to make some small changes: set the arrays (x,y,d1,d2) to empty when output is defined in order to avoid them to append everything in the further iteration; add conddition when an empty line appears in the loop befor LI #(the code was stopping) and change the parenthesis by brackets to append. Works like a charm!

Comment: Glad that it worked out for you. Would you mind marking it as the answer if it satisfies your needs?

Comment: Sure, I did! I can't vote on it because of my reputation but I checked as the answer, thanks again.